# MySQL subquery unwanted result

Tags: mysql

so I have come into this subquery

```
SELECT movies.movieID, movies.user 
FROM movies
WHERE movies.user IN(Select movies.user 
                     FROM movies 
                     WHERE movies.movieID = '19') 
AND movies.movieID <> (SELECT movies.movieID 
                           FROM movies 
                           WHERE movies.user='5'
                           AND movies.movieID = '19') 
AND movies.movieID <> '19'
```

and it gives me this result

```
--------------------------
|  movieID    | user     |
--------------------------
|    20       |   4      |
--------------------------
|    21       |   4      |
--------------------------
|    22       |   5      |
--------------------------
|    23       |   4      |
--------------------------
```

How can I get rid of any result that is from user 5?

I think the problem is at the

```
AND movies.movieID <> (SELECT movies.movieID 
                           FROM movies 
                           WHERE movies.user='5'
                           AND movies.movieID = '19')
```

But When I try to run the query alone

```
SELECT movies.movieID 
FROM movies 
WHERE movies.user='5'
AND movies.movieID = '19'
```

it gives me only 1 result out of 2, which is only 19, the movieID 22 is not returned. Where the result of this query is correct. Why the 22 is returned when I run it in subquery?

Can anybody help me please? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want the records with user = 5 then just add

```
AND movies.user <> '5'
```

Your subquery

```
SELECT movies.movieID 
FROM movies 
WHERE movies.user='5'
AND movies.movieID = '19'
```

says, select the movieID where the movieID is 19 and the user is 5. This query will return 19.

So this

```
AND movies.movieID <> (SELECT movies.movieID 
                       FROM movies 
                       WHERE movies.user='5'
                       AND movies.movieID = '19')
```

says I don't want movieID = 19, which is why in your final query you will still get the record with movieID = 5.

Comment: omg sir, yes! it works! after tweakin the codes here and there for several hours, made me completely out of my mind! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The clause where you are filtering out the records with user = '5' is only filtering out records where the user = '5' and movieID = '19'

```
AND movies.movieID <> (SELECT movies.movieID 
                           FROM movies 
                           WHERE movies.user='5'
                           AND movies.movieID = '19')
```

This means that it is not filtering out the record where user = '5' and movieID = '22'

Depending on what you want, you might try:

```
AND movies.movieID <> (SELECT movies.movieID 
                           FROM movies 
                           WHERE movies.user='5'
                           OR movies.movieID = '19')
```

or just add `AND user != 5` on the main `WHERE` clause

```
SELECT movies.movieID, movies.user 
FROM movies
WHERE movies.user IN(Select movies.user 
                     FROM movies 
                     WHERE movies.movieID = '19') 
AND movies.movieID <> (SELECT movies.movieID 
                           FROM movies 
                           WHERE movies.user='5'
                           AND movies.movieID = '19') 
AND movies.movieID <> '19'
AND user <> '5'
```